# could catalepsy be caused by being beaten in the street?

Tags: diagnosis

I am writing a story of a character named Eric who lives in D.C., and got jumped by 3 tough Mancunian visitors and beaten to the point of being left in a condition of falling in and out of trance-like states.
Would this be catalepsy, or could a beating cause catalepsy?  If not, what is that condition in which Eric would fall in and out of trances starting right after and because of this heavy beating he received?
Remember, I'm going for accuracy in this story, hence why I am asking if it would be catalepsy that was caused by this beating he received. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly so. Head trauma can lead to the development of epilepsy, which is a disorder characterized by chronic seizures, also having catalepsy as a symptom. It may be a different disorder, depending on how the trances present themselves. If you want the trances to be chronic, multiple over time, this leads to the question of whether or not there's a trigger. If you want it to be triggered by, say, a loud noise, it would be considered Post Traumatic Stress disorder. This might result in him curling up in a ball on the ground, or screaming, and becoming somewhat unresponsive. I believe you're looking for Atypical Absence Seizures, during which the person having the seizures stares straight ahead, becomes unresponsive. These episodes are only considered "Atypical" if they last longer than 20 seconds. Otherwise, they're just called Absence Seizures. You'll need to start being concerned if the seizure lasts longer than five minutes. Either way, they're symptoms of Myoclonic Astatic Epilepsy.
Hope this helps!
A few helpful websites for more information:

https://www.epilepsy.com/learn/types-seizures/absence-seizures
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myoclonic_astatic_epilepsy
http://doosesyndrome.org/mae-explained/absence-seizures?phpMyAdmin=6847bcaa11f3a4c4a30eee927e12da01

Comment: ah, I never realized that epilepsy and catalepsy could be linked like that.